# How to run the CLI in my application resource on OS X? I use Objective-C and Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, ffmpeg, command-line-interface

How to run the CLI in my application resource on OS X? I use Objective-C and Xcode. Now I am using the ShellWrapper and Pipe. I have placed FFMpeg(CLI) on **/Volumes/Work** and run **"/Volumes/Work/FFmpeg"** and the result is no problem. But I don't know if I place the ffmpeg into my project resource, how can I run it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution.

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:];
```

Works great :)